# Please suggest with typeerror in python

Tags: python

I got a question which says "Write a function user prints even number from list). We have to ask the user to input a list. I am getting a "Type Error: not all arguments converted during string formatting". Please help were am I wrong.

```
def even_no(x):
        a = x.split()
        new_list = []
        for i in a:
                if i % 2 == 0:
                        new_list.append(i)
input_no = input("Enter number sequence: ")
print(even_no(input_no))
```

Answer (score 1):

`%` is also use for string formatting, and since the `split` method belongs to `string`, it also returns a `string`, hence, the interpreter tries to format it.

change the line:

```
if i % 2 == 0:
```

to

```
if int(i) % 2 == 0:
```

that your code should work.

As a side note, your function won't print anything because there's no return for the `even_no` function

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to convert the numbers from `str` to `int`. `map` can be used for this. Also you did not return your list.

```
def even_no(x):
    a = map(int, x.split())
    new_list = []
    for i in a:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list

input_no = input("Enter number sequence: ")
print(even_no(input_no))
```

Execution example:

```
Enter number sequence: 10 20 30
[10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `indentation` was a bit so I fixed that and you also forgot to use `return`. I fixed all of that including your `TypeError`. Here is the code:

```
def even_no(x):
    a = x.split()
    new_list = []
    for i in a:
        if int(i) % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
input_no = input("Enter number sequence: ")
print(even_no(input_no))
```

Comment: While I agree for the return part, I do not see any indentation error on the OP's code

Comment: That's true there was no indentation problem, however the spacing in the indentation was a bit off so i fixed that. Maybe I should better clarify it. I will be editing it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues to be noted. 
The first one has already been mentioned, which is the need to convert strings to integers.
The second is with the following line:
input_no = input("Enter number sequence: ") .
When I tested, the function "even_no" would not execute with the above line present as a global variable.
To overcome this problem I used tkinter and a class in the following code.
Please note: This allows the user to enter a number or numbers into an entry field. Each number should be separated by a space. Only numbers should be used.
If any even numbers are entered, they will be printed into a list in the python shell. If No even numbers are entered, an empty list will be printed. If non-numeric characters are entered, the Value Error is handled to guide the user on the correct method of input.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, messagebox
import tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from tkinter import *


class Control(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.controller = self



        self.shared_data = {
            "input_no": tk.StringVar(),
        }

        self.title('Even')

        self.entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.shared_data["input_no"])
        self.entry.pack()

        self.enterbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Enter',
                                    command=(self.even_no)
                                     )

        self.enterbutton.pack()

    def even_no(self):
        try:
            user_input = self.shared_data["input_no"].get()
            a = user_input.split()
            new_list = []
            for i in a:
                if int(i) % 2 == 0:
                    new_list.append(int(i))
            print(new_list)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid Entry. Please enter numbers only. \n'
                  'Please make sure that each number is separated by a space.')


Control1 = Control()

Control1.mainloop()
```